# Parse string as of certain point

Tags: android, regex, replace

if I have a string like below example how can I keep the **1.23 (8752)** ?

Example:

```
Testversion v1.23 (8752), beta v1.02 (458)
```

I am trying with regex but I am unlucky so far, this only gives 1.23:

```
String result = input.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

Comment: PCRE would be `\d+\.\d+ \(\d+\)`, maybe it can help you find your solution.

You need to double your slash too (\d in my comment, you need to write \\d)

Comment: Hi, you mean replaceAll("\\d+\\.\\(\\d+\\)", ""); ?
Gives me unfortunatly same output as I have.

Comment: I'm sorry i cant test with a java version, so im trying with PHP^^ Cant help you more right now, good luck! Or maybe  replaceAll("\\d+\\.\\(\\d+\\)", ""); (double escaping the parenthesis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.*?(v\\d+\\.\\d+\\s*\\(\\d+\\)).*`

```
input.replaceFirst(".*?(v\\d+\\.\\d+\\s*\\(\\d+\\)).*", "$1"); //v1.23 (8752)
```

[**Java Demo Link**](https://ideone.com/A8aepQ)

Explanation

`.*?(v\\d+\\.\\d+\\s*\\(\\d+\\)).*` : `.*?` match anything as less as possible

- `(v\\d+\\.\\d+\\s*\\(\\d+\\))` : `(` beginning of capturing group

  - `v\\d+\\.\\d+` : match `v`, `\\d+` one or more digits `.` character , `\\d+`
  - `\\s*\\(\\d+\\)`  : `\\s*` zero or more spaces then `(` one or more digits `)`

  `).*` : end of capturing group , `.*` match anything till end of line